# Getting java.util.Date Object As (10/7/14 ) From Another java.util.Date Object (Tue Oct 07 11:21:00 IST 2014)

Tags: java, timestamp, java.util.date

Am facing problem while using @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
recently we started migrating our project from struts2 to spring 
while we are using @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) in struts2 for a
java.util.Date field able to retrieve the Date field data as 10/7/14 but coming to springs the same Date field data is retrieving as Tue Oct 07 11:21:00 IST 2014

So,why spring is unable to convert the Tue Oct 07 11:21:00 IST 2014 to 10/7/14  which is a java.util.Date object internally.

How we can achieve this conversion of  Tue Oct 07 11:21:00 IST 2014 to 10/7/14 as a java.util.Date Object.

Any help is greatly appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

How to format?

```
String str="Tue Oct 07 11:21:00 IST 2014";
Date date=new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ssZ yyyy").parse(str);
System.out.println(date);
//now you can format this date to any format
//eg
DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/d/yy");
System.out.println(df.format(date));
```

Out put:

```
Tue Oct 07 11:21:00 IST 2014
10/7/14
```

Comment: Actually it was the perfect solution but i don't want 10/7/14 as a string output i just want 10/7/14 as java.util.Date object.Is there any other solution that you can come up with.

Answer (score 2):

The format "Tue Oct 07 11:21:00 IST 2014" is the default format if you dump a java.util.Date to string. It has **no** actual string representation apart from this.

If you want to stringify your date in a particular format, look at SimpleDateFormat.